# Is ETL or UL necessary to retail AC chargers?

Tags: united-states, business

Theoretical: I wish to import and sell wall chargers in the USA.

I realize it is a good idea to get a safety certificate that signifies my product meets national safety standards to avoid being sued.

However, my question is whether it is legal to sell them without a safety certificate (ETL, UL, etc).